# Can I "put" an open tab/page on my iPhone from my Mac?

Tags: icloud, safari, tabs

I recently, stupidly, deleted all my Safari data on my iPhone and in the process lost all my open tabs (191 in total, yes, that's how I do things).

Anyway, I managed to get to my Mac before it synced and took a backup of the CloudTabs.db file, so I have all the URLs.

So I would like to get some of those tabs back onto the iPhone. Is there any easy way to do this? I have tried copying or dragging URLs into the iCloud Tabs list, but it's not possible. You can only seem to open or delete the tabs on another device.

> The long way would be to open all URLs in Safari on macOS, and then open each one individually in iOS.